# Can Dijkstra's Algorithm work on a graph with weights of 0?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, breadth-first-search, path-finding

If there exists a **weighted graph** `G`, and **all weights** are `0`, does Dijkstra's algorithm still find the shortest path? If so, why?

As per my understanding of the algorithm, Dijsktra's algorithm will run like a normal **BFS** if there are no edge weights, but I would appreciate some clarification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Explanation

Dijkstra itself has no problem with `0` weight, per definition of the algorithm. It only gets problematic with **negative** weights.

Since in every round Dijkstra will **settle** a node. If you later find a negative weighted edge, this could lead to a **shorter path** to that settled node. The node would then need to be **unsettled**, which Dijkstras algorithm does **not allow** (and it would break the complexity of the algorithm). It gets clear if you take a look at the actual algorithm and some illustration.

The behavior of Dijkstra on such an *all zero*-graph is the same as if all edges would have a different, but same, value, like `1` (except of the resulting shortest path length). Dijkstra will simply visit all nodes, in no particular order. Basically, like an ordinary **Breadth-first search**.

---

### Details

Take a look at the algorithm description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm):

```
 1 function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3     create vertex set Q
 4
 5     for each vertex v in Graph:           // Initialization
 6         dist[v] ← INFINITY                // Unknown distance from source to v
 7         prev[v] ← UNDEFINED               // Previous node in optimal path from source
 8         add v to Q                        // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
 9
10     dist[source] ← 0                      // Distance from source to source
11      
12     while Q is not empty:
13         u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]  // Node with the least distance
14                                           // will be selected first
15         remove u from Q 
16          
17         for each neighbor v of u:         // where v is still in Q.
18             alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
19             if alt < dist[v]:             // A shorter path to v has been found
20                 dist[v] ← alt 
21                 prev[v] ← u 
22
23     return dist[], prev[]
```

The problem with negative values lies in line `15` and `17`. When you remove node `u`, you **settle** it. That is, you say that the shortest path to this node is now known. But that means you won't consider `u` again in line `17` as a neighbor of some other node (since it's not contained in `Q` anymore).

With negative values it could happen that you later find a shorter path (due to negative weights) to that node. You would need to consider `u` again in the algorithm and re-do all the computation that depended on the previous shortest path to `u`. So you would need to add `u` and every other node that was removed from `Q` that had `u` on its shortest path back to `Q`.

Especially, you would need to consider **all edges** that could lead to your destination, since you never know where some nasty `-1_000_000` weighted edge hides.

The following example illustrates the problem:

[image]

Dijkstra will declare the red way as shortest path from `A` to `C`, with length `0`. However, there is a shorter path. It is marked blue and has a length of `99 - 300 + 1 = -200`.

With negative weights you could even create a more dangerous scenario, **negative cycles**. That is a cycle in the graph with a negative total weight. You then need a way to stop moving along the cycle all the time, endlessly dropping your current weight.

---

### Notes

In an undirected graph edges with weight `0` can be **eliminated** and the nodes be **merged**. A shortest path between them will always have length `0`. If the whole graph only has `0` weights, then the graph could just be merged to one node. The result to every shortest path query is simply `0`.

The same holds for directed graphs if you have such an edge in both directions. If not, you can't do that optimization as you would change reach-ability of nodes.

Comment: Good answer but this line isn't quite right "The behavior of Dijkstra on such an all zero-graph is the same as if all edges would have a different, but same, value, like 1", e.g. A--1--B--1--C--1--D has a distance of 3 from A to D but all zeros puts every node at the same distance.

Comment: @IanMercer While that is correct, the Dijkstra algorithm will nonetheless behave the same. In the sense of which nodes it visits in which order etc. That's what I wanted to say here :) But thanks, will edit.

Comment: Re your last paragraph: The nodes can only be merged in an undirected graph (or if the nodes are connected in both directions with weight 0)